# Present participle or gerund for describing means

Tags: grammaire, participe-présent

> J'ai mangé le steak (utilisant / en utilisant) un couteau.

Should we use the present participle (utilisant) or the gerund (en utilisant) in this case, or do both work? I think both should work, since *utilisant* would modify the subject *je*, indicating that I ate using the knife. Using the gerund *en utilisant* would modify the whole phrase, saying that the action of eating steak was done using the knife.

Does the answer change if we change the order in the sentence?

> (Utilisant / En utilisant) un couteau, j'ai mangé le steak.

or

> Philippe, (utilisant / en utilisant) un couteau, a mangé le steak.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gerund is used:

> *J'ai mangé le steak en utilisant une fourchette* (or simply: *avec une fourchette*).

or

> *J'ai coupé le steak en utilisant un couteau.* (or better: à l'aide d'un couteau)

or

> *Ne mange-pas ton steak avec ton couteau / avec les doigts !*

If you change the order, present participle would be used:

> *Utilisant un couteau, j'ai coupé le steak.* (*Avec un couteau, j'ai coupé le steak*).

You would use the gerund if there is no direct or intentional relationship between the clauses (while doing something, something else happened …):

> *En utilisant un couteau, je me suis coupé.*
>
> *En me rasant, j'ai reçu un coup de fil.*

Note that your example is odd. It is very unusual to **eat** a steak with a knife. You cut up a steak with a knife but you eat it with a fork, maybe sticks or whatever but not a knife. That's the reason why I replaced *couteau* by *fourchette* and *mangé* by *coupé* to get meaningful sentences.

Comment: Thanks. What about this order: "Philippe, (utilisant / en utilisant) un couteau, a mangé le steak." Which one should be used?

Comment: @user11550 - sounds like both would work to me - but the whole sentence starts sounding a bit unnatural to me. I would stick to: "Philippe a mangé son steak avec un couteau."

Answer (score 2):

For the example of the *couteau*, I would naturally say:

> J'ai mangé le steak avec un couteau.

But:

> J'ai mangé le steak en utilisant un couteau.

sounds forced or too complicated, or too formal, or uncommon to me - thought it is correct.

For fun, I used Google n-grams viewer to look at statistics of *avec* vs. *en utilisant*. I do not know what corpus Google is using, so I would be careful in interpreting these results.

[image]

Watch out! In the diagram below, the frequency of *avec* is multiplied by .05.

[image]

Comment: I don't think there is an issue with Google's French corpus. *Avec* is definitely much more common than *utilisant*. Comparing "with" and "using" leads also to a wide difference. You used a wrong separator (`;` instead of `,`) between *à l'aide de* and *grâce à* in your second ngram, the reason why these expressions do not show up.

Comment: @jlliagre - Thanks, I'll fix the second diagram. What I meant about the corpus is not that there is something wrong, but that we don't know what it is. But I would agree: _avec_ is simply much more common than _utilisant_. Maybe that comparison is not so interesting after all - i.e. we "knew" the result...

Comment: The corpus is made of OCR'd scanned books, the ones that show up in the links. There are likely several hundreds of thousands of them. You might want to rescale *avec* in your graph for the other curves to be visible, for example using `(avec * .05),à l'aide de,grâce à,utilisant`

Comment: Done for the diagram. I am not saying that the corpus is bad. I just want to be careful.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @jlliagre. For the deeper answer, there is a distinction between the gerund and the present participle.

I like the following explanation: http://www.francaisfacile.com/exercices/exercice-francais-2/exercice-francais-83422.php

Essentially,

- With the **gerund** the **subject of the two verbs must be the same.** It expresses an idea of a second activity/state taking place while/because a first one is taking place *for the same person*.
- A first **use case of the present participle** is as a replacement of a relative sentence (*qui ...*). I would say that in that case, it tends toward the formal, poetic, or downright archaic.
- The present participle can also be used to express **a cause** (*étant malade, il n'a pas pu venir*). It is more formal, i.e. it is more idiomatic for written language than spoken language.

For the first use case of the present participle, compare:

> Il observait les nuages qui couraient dans le ciel.
>
> Il observait les nuages courant dans le ciel.
>
> Il observait les nuages courants.

While the first is ordinary, the second sentence instantly takes a more poetic connotation.

The third, with the form used as **adjective** (i.e. plural) is completely different (it means, as in the borrowed English equivalent, *current*). This transformation into an adjective requires frequent use in order to enter the common language. It sounds therefore matter-of-fact (in this case it sounds as jargon: perhaps a meteorologist would use it).

Note also that the original present participle was also intransitive (no complement) and used metaphorically (with the idea of "existing for some time"; we can draw a parallel with a similar usage of the English adjective *running* with a meaning of time, e.g. *a long-running discussion*).