# When to use "en" on gerund?

Tags: grammaire, participe-présent

I have encountered some sentences that use the gerund with or without *en*. For example:

> La reine allait et venait, mangeant du pain et de la confiture.
>
> En passant par cette porte, on est arrivés avant les autres.
>
> Elle est partie en disant des choses agréables.
>
> Ayant bien vendu sa maison, elle était presque riche.

But I'm not sure when to use *en* and when not to use it. For me, all of these sentences are fine with or without *en*, and the meaning is same.

So what is the grammar rule based on?

Comment: Related: https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/24332/present-participle-or-gerund-for-describing-means

Comment: Fyi, it can be used to translate: while or by or in followed by a participle. En passant par cette porte, **by** going through that door or **in** going through that door//en disant des choses agreables, **while** saying nice things. So, it in English, you have: "In talking that way, you will get yourself fired. En parlant comme ça, tu te feras virer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The *gérondif* is built by prepending the preposition *en* to the *participe-présent*.

It has all the characteristics of an adverb. It is linked to a verb and provides a piece of information that is close to it.

On the other hand, the *participe-présent* is linked to a nominal group and is a verbal form, it introduces an action.

The nuance is sometimes tenuous.

In your first sentence, both actions are only loosely coupled so the *participe-présent* is used. Using *en mangeant* is possible, even more in spoken French, but that might imply she had to stop walking when done eating.

The second sentence:

> *En passant par cette porte, on est arrivé avant les autres.*

means:

> Because we passed through that door, we arrived before the others.

but:

> *Passant par cette porte, on est arrivé avant les autres.*

would mean:

> While passing through that door, we arrived before the others.

There might be no relationship between the fact they passed through that door and the fact they arrived first.

In the third sentence, *elle est partie en disant...* is strongly linking both verbs. She left and slandered in a single action.

The last sentence is more tricky but is absolutely correct.

> *Ayant bien vendu sa maison*

is something that happened once but

> *elle était presque riche*

is a state that lasted a long period of time, so the coupling is weak.

Should we want to use the gerund, we can can replace the second part with a form that is consistent with it:

> ***En** ayant bien vendu sa maison, elle était **devenue** presque riche*

where both actions are linked and can be merged in a single event.

Here is another example from the [OQLF](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?t1=1&id=2915) where the gerund is also unused, this time because the first action is long lasting so cannot apply to the second action which is discrete :

> *S’ennuyant au travail, elle a décidé de reprendre ses études.*

To go further, you can read an interesting article by Marie-Pierre Escoubas-Benveniste comparing the respective usage of the *participe présent* and the *gérondif* in spoken French vs written French.

[Usages du gérondif et du participe présent en français parlé et écrit : étude comparée basée sur corpus](https://journals.openedition.org/tipa/911)

Here is also [a web page in English about the French present participle](https://www.lawlessfrench.com/grammar/present-participle/).

Answer (score -2):

Il faut tout d'abord une revue de la grammaire dans ses essentiels pour toutes les formes grammaticales que la question implique ; seulement ensuite devient-il plus aisé d'essayer de fournir une explication.

**I**

> (TLFi) II. [Analyse sém.]
>   C. [En introduit une forme en -ant pour former un gérondif fonctionnant comme un compl. circ.]
>
> - **[de moyen]** C'est **en forgeant** qu'on devient forgeron.
> - **[de temps]** Écoute, dit Dubreuilh, tout **en le soignant**, essaie donc de le cuisiner .
> - **[de manière]**  Malheureux les conscrits Devant le stand de tir Visant le cœur du monde Visant leur propre cœur Visant le cœur du monde **En éclatant de rire**. (PRÉVERT, Paroles, 1946 p. 223)

Le site du [reverso](http://grammaire.reverso.net/1_1_23_Le_gerondif.shtml) explique ceci ;

> **Le gérondif est un mode qui se forme avec le participe présent** (formes en -ant) précédé de en. Il est employé dans la fonction de complément circonstanciel.
>
> - Il parle en dormant (= pendant qu'il dort).
> - Nous avons appris la nouvelle ce matin en arrivant.

L'[encyclopédie libre](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%C3%A9rondif) dit ceci ;

> Hérité du gerundium latin, le gérondif est une forme verbale. **En français, il est formé comme un participe présent précédé de la préposition en**.
>
> Son sujet étant toujours le même que celui du verbe conjugué, le gérondif ne peut jamais être le centre d'une proposition.
>
> Le gérondif a un double sens : verbe et adverbe. Comme l'adverbe, le gérondif a une fonction de complément circonstanciel. En tant que verbe, il donne des fonctions spécifiques à d'autres éléments de la phrase. Il est utilisé pour indiquer la simultanéité d'un fait qui a lieu dans le cadre d'un autre fait. 
>   Exemple : En rentrant, j'ai croisé mon voisin.
>
> En français, le gérondif est une forme verbale invariable, composée du participe présent précédé de la préposition en, employée comme complément circonstanciel du verbe principal.
>
> En français moderne, le gérondif est une des trois formes verbales en -ant. Les deux autres sont l'adjectif verbal et le participe présent.
>
> En français il existe deux temps pour le gérondif. Ainsi, le français forme sur le verbe « travailler » au gérondif :
>  
>   en travaillant : gérondif présent ;
>  
>   en ayant travaillé : gérondif passé.
>
> Chacun possède une seule forme verbale, invariable.

La [BDL](https://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?t1=1&id=4712)
 stipule la particularité suivante de l'usage ;

> Pour des raisons de clarté, le participe présent ou **le gérondif** dont le sujet est sous-entendu **doit en principe renvoyer au sujet de la phrase (ou de la subordonnée) dans laquelle il s’insère**. Notons que ce participe présent ou ce gérondif peut être **employé seul** ou **former le noyau d’un groupe de mots plus complexe**.

**II**

Voici ce que dit [l'encyclopédie libre](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proposition_participiale) sur la proposition participiale, autrement dit la construction grammaticale qu'entraine le participe présent ;

> La proposition subordonnée participiale est une proposition qui n'est introduite par aucun mot subordonnant. **Elle est séparée du verbe de la proposition principale par un signe de ponctuation** (virgule, tirets ou parenthèses). Par ailleurs, elle est mobile dans la phrase.
>
> - Le temps aidant, elle l'oubliera. / Elle l'oubliera, le temps aidant.
>
> La proposition subordonnée participiale contient un verbe au participe passé ou présent et **son thème** (on ne peut parler ici de sujet), qu'il ne partage avec aucun autre verbe.
>
> - L'hiver venu, elle fut démunie.
> - Les grilles s'ouvrant, les clients se précipitent dans le magasin.
>
> Dans l'exemple ci-dessus, le participe s'ouvrant a un thème, les grilles, à lui seul ; il ne le partage pas avec la forme verbale « se précipitèrent » !
>
> - S'impatientant, le candidat perdit son sang-froid.
>
> Dans ce cas, il n'y a pas de proposition subordonnée participiale, puisque le participe partage son thème avec le verbe de la proposition principale. C'est le candidat qui s'impatiente et c'est lui aussi qui perd son sang-froid.
>
> Le thème précède le participe.
>
> - S'ouvrant les grilles, les clients se précipitèrent dans le magasin.
>
> Fonctions de la proposition subordonnée participiale
>   Elle peut exercer la fonction de complément circonstanciel facultatif de :
>
> **[cause]** Toutes les indications étant fausses, nous nous perdîmes. 
>   **[temps]** Le soleil se couchant, nous rentrâmes.

**III**

En se rapportant à l'information rassemblée dans « **I** » et « **II** » on peut considérer les choses sur une base plus claire.

**A/** Tout d'abord, il faut ne pas confondre participe présent et gérondif et comprendre que la nature du gérondif, bien que fondamentalement verbale, est aussi adverbiale, d'où les notions de CC qui lui sont associées, CC soit de moyen, soit de temps, soit de manière.

**B/** Secondement on doit s'apercevoir que la question est celle du choix entre le gérondif dont les catégories de fonction en tant que CC  sont moyen, temps et manière, une proposition subordonnée participiale dont les catégories sur ce même niveau sont cause et temps, et un adjectif verbal.

**C/** On peut maintenant essayer d'expliquer les différences.

**phrase 1**  La reine allait et venait, mangeant du pain et de la confiture.

Il ne s'agit pas d'une proposition  subordonnée participiale parce qu'il n'existe pas de <<*thème*>> (autrement appelé « sujet sous-entendu »)  et la forme verbale est du type « adjectivale apposée » ;

*La reine allait et venait, en partie occupée à manger du pain …*

Il n'y a qu'une subtile différence entre l'utilisation du gérondif et celle de l'adjectif verbal : dans le premier cas « manger » est l'occupation centrale, dans le second elle est accessoire.

- Je le lui ai dit, dans le passé, en parlant d'un autre problème. *L'occupation centrale est de parler d'un autre problème, ce qui est dit (le) est incident à cet évènement.*
- Je le lui ai dit, dans le passé, parlant d'un autre problème. *L'occupation centrale est de dire quelque chose ; ce quelque chose peut être un autre problème.*

**phrase 2** En passant par cette porte, on est arrivés avant les autres.

Il s'agit d'un gérondif et la fonction est le moyen ; on veut insister sur le moyen qui a permis d'arriver avant. Si on supprime la particule, la construction est adjectivale parce le « *thème* » manque, (qui passe par cette porte ? on) ;  on n'insiste plus sur le moyen, il n'y a plus qu'une apposition adjectivale ;

Passant par cette porte, on est arrivés avant les autres.

On peut se rendre compte de cela en ajoutant des éléments;

- Passant par cette porte et prenant tout notre temps, sans nous inquiéter, on est arrivé avant les autres. *On suspecte beaucoup moins l'idée de moyen ; en fait elle ne doit pas exister, ni dans cet exemple « long » ni autrement.*

**phrase 3** Elle est partie en disant des choses agréables.

Le gérondif est ici un CC de manière ; on insiste sur la façon dont le départ est effectué ; si on supprime la particule, encore une fois on n'a pas de subordonnée participiale, et donc une apposition adjectivale (Elle est partie  *animée* de paroles agréables.)

**phrase 4** Ayant bien vendu sa maison, elle était presque riche.

Cette phrase est anormale ; d'après la BDL ces formes sont fautives ; cela correspond à la nature causale qui s'impose pour cet état de chose (maison bien vendue) et que l'on n'a pas dans une tournure adjectivale, ce qu'est "ayant bien vendu sa maison" dans cette phrase.

> (BDL) - Étant en retard, Michèle peste contre son mari.
>
> On écrira plutôt :
>
> - Michèle, qui est en retard, peste contre son mari.

On écrira donc ceci ;

> Sa maison ayant été bien vendue, elle était presque riche. *Nous avons maintenant une subordonnée participiale parce qu'il existe un* « thème » *(maison) et la cause est explicitement justifiée par la forme.*

Dans cette phrase, bien qu'il puisse exister un état d'esprit personnel qui tend à empêcher de voir une différence, il y a une différence importante : il n'est pas possible d'utiliser « en », c'est de toute évidence faux.

**IV**

Il est utile de considérer les remarques suivantes de la [BDL](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?t1=1&id=4712) ;

La règle qui vient d’être énoncée comporte cependant de nombreuses exceptions, notamment dans les textes littéraires. **En réalité, quand le contexte permet d'éliminer toute équivoque, on accorde bien souvent peu d’attention à des structures qui devraient pourtant être considérées comme mal construites selon la règle**¹. À ce propos, mentionnons le cas de certaines tournures passives ou impersonnelles et de phrases dans lesquelles le sujet sous-entendu du participe présent ou du gérondif, très général, peut être remplacé par on.

¹ <sub>caractères gras ajoutés à l'original</sub>

> Exemples :
>
> - En approchant de la mer, le terrain s’élève. (F.-R. de Chateaubriand)
> - L’appétit vient en mangeant. (proverbe)
> - Maria n’ira pas bien loin car, en quittant la maison, ses pieds étaient déjà endoloris.
> - Sincèrement parlant, tu ne peux présenter une théorie aussi loufoque lors de ce congrès!
> - Cette facette de la question de l’immigration devra être étudiée en tenant compte des plus récentes études démographiques.
> - Te couchant toujours tôt, il faisait encore clair lorsque tu t’es mise au lit.
> - Supposant que Carey Price continue de bien jouer, les Canadiens pourraient accéder aux quarts de finale.
> - En logeant dans un hôtel aussi luxueux, les soucis quotidiens du voyageur deviennent inexistants.

Comment: 1. Using *malgré que* is provocative. 2. What OQLF rule do you consider to state *Ayant bien vendu sa maison, elle était presque riche* to be abnormal ?

Comment: @jlliagre 1. Provocatif pour le lecteur ? Je ne vois pas en quoi. 2. Selon le fait que le schéma est le même que celui de la phrase fournie par la BDL : « Étant en retard, Michèle peste contre son mari. » ; c'est Michèle qui est en retard et de même c'est « elle » (qui étant presque riche) est créditée comme ayant vendu la maison) donc dans les deux cas il n'y a pas de proposition participiale et apparemment cela laisse l'option du participe présent à valeur d'adjectif donc pas de CC de cause alors qu'une cause est assez clairement ce que l'auteur choisit d'exprimer.

Comment: 1. Les seules personnes que je connais dont les oreilles ne sont pas écorchées par *malgré que* n'auraient jamais l'idée de visiter FSE. Elles sont plutôt du genre à jouer dans les cours de récréation ou à hurler dans les stades de foot, malgré que je ne condamne ni l'un ni l'autre ;-). 2. Non, tu n'as rien compris à l'exemple. C'est le mari qui est en retard !

Comment: @jlliagre En ce qui concerne l'exemple, il y a deux possibilités, toutes deux inappropriées pour le contexte grammatical ; c'est la seconde que j'ai choisie : « Michèle, qui est en retard, peste contre son mari. ». Je crois comprendre en ce qui concerne « malgré que » : c'est la recommandation de l'Ac.  Je n'y pense pas mais je ne commet pas une faute si impardonnable ; [La locution « malgré que » fait aujourd'hui partie du langage oral et écrit, même chez les plus grands auteurs.](http://www.zcorrecteurs.fr/blog/billet-218-peut-on-dire-malgre-que.html)

Comment: La recommandation de l'Académie est de ne pas utiliser *malgré que*. Je n'ai de toute façon pas dit que c'était incorrect mais que c'était de la provocation. Peux-tu indiquer la règle de la BDL, puisque tu indiques t'appuyer sur elle, qui implique que la forme 4 est fautive ?

Comment: @jlliagre La BDL ne donne pas la règle explicitement ; je la déduis sur la base de leur assertion à l'effet que la construction devrait être évitée et des principes sémantiques et grammaticaux qui ne concordent pas, ni plus ni moins que le raisonnement dans le commentaire précédent (que l'on retrouve dans ma réponse plusieurs fois). Pour que la sémantique et la grammaire concorde il faut changer la construction. À preuve du contraire je suis convaincu de cela. Si je devais essayer de formuler une règle, je dirais qu'il faut que la grammaire se prête à la sémantique, mais c'est bien général.

Comment: @jlliagre Qu'est-ce que c'est cette idée de provocation ? Je n'y suis pas du tout.

Comment: Tu as écrit : *d'après la BDL ces formes sont fautives*. Si tu n'y trouves rien qui supporte cette affirmation, remplace la par *d'après moi*.

Comment: @jlliagre Voici le texte, que l'on trouve au moyen du lien BDL dans ma réponse : Exemples fautifs :
 
-  Espérant une réponse positive, veuillez recevoir, Monsieur, l’expression de mes sentiments distingués.
-  Étant en retard, Michèle peste contre son mari.
 
On écrira plutôt :
 
-  Espérant une réponse positive, je vous prie de recevoir, Monsieur, l’expression de mes sentiments distingués.
-  Michèle, qui est en retard, peste contre son mari.
-  Son mari étant en retard, Michèle peste contre lui.

Comment: Perdu. La page de la BDL traite de l'incohérence entre le sujet du participe et celui du verbe de la phrase ou de la subordonnée. Ce n'est pas *monsieur* qui espère une réponse positive mais la personne qui écrit la lettre, ce n'est pas *Michèle* qui est en retard mais son mari. Dans le cas de la phrase 4, il y a cohérence entre ***elle*** a vendu sa maison et ***elle*** était presque riche.

Comment: @jlliagre Selon l'encyclopédie libre la construction « Ayant vendu sa maison » n'est pas une subordonnée participiale, et seulement les participiales peuvent avoir la fonction de CC de cause, pas les participes à valeur d'adjectif ; il est dit dans leur explication que la construction n'a pas de thème ou encore qu'il est le même que pour la principale, ce qui est équivalent à dire qu'elle n'en a pas ; c'est la raison pour laquelle il n'existe pas une proposition participiale ; il sont épithètes ou apposés ; donc cela n'a pas de sens.

Comment: *Ayant eu hier (enfin) la visite du Major qui m'a ajourné à quelques mois, je m'étais promis de changer mes heures pour pouvoir vivre un peu de jour.* Marcel Proust, 1915.

Comment: @jlliagre Oui, mais aussi : Jamais Noé ne put si bien voir le monde que de l'arche, malgré qu'elle fût close et qu'il fît nuit sur la terre. (Proust)

Comment: N'est pas Proust qui veut... Déplorant ton obstination, je te conseille de t'instruire des groupes participiaux en français, par exemple en lisant [cette page](http://www.alloprof.qc.ca/BV/pages/f1242.aspx) où tu verras que cette construction courante a un sens.